# Oracle SQL Developer - Query results window with grid missing

Tags: oracle, oracleclient, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've just made the switch from MS sql server to Oracle.  The query tool I am using is Oracle SQL Developer.  The problem I am having is that I cannot get the query results window to stick around. The query results window being the Grid view for the results.  It seems to show up arbitrarily when I open a new "sql worksheet".  But not always.  Then once I run a query, it disappears the next time I run one.

Can anyone point me to a consistent way to leave this results grid active? Thanks so much.

Comment: What version are you using? There are other tools out there, such as JOra (an Eclipse plugin), Squirrel SQL, and Allround Automation SQL Developer (commercial product - decent but has its own quirks).

Comment: What version of SQL Developer are you using?

Comment: v2.1.1.  I'm being told by the powers that be to stick with this tool unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 265, accepted):

ok guys. figured it out.  I was hitting F5 (as in MSSQL query analyzer) to run the query.  That is "run script" in this client.  <kbd>F9</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> get me to the query results grid view.  Hopefully this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Yeah, now that sounds familiar (I think I've done that once or twice, but so long ago...). And in some tools it's F8. I think it's possible to remap that if you want to be consistent with other tools.

Comment: Thanks! Also digging into Oracle, this SQL developer makes this a lot easier than Toad. Man that thing has so many buttons it makes my head hurt!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479408/execute-statement-or-run-script

Comment: Yeah, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio uses F5. It's a common thing to try to use F5 on Oracle. Did the same thing. But that was my case, I was using MS SQL Management studio.

Comment: Having previously worked with SSMS F5 is hard-wired in my mind, so I reassigned F5 in SQL Developer to run the query.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me too. Tools > Preferences > Shortcut Keys for anyone that wants to remap "Run Statement" to F5.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same issue. in Script output only line apearing was

> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

`set SERVEROUTPUT ON` helped in this case.

Comment: There's also the Dbms Output window (View > Dbms Output). Click the plus button to add DBMS_OUTPUT to your connection.