# Oracle SQL Developer query result out missing grid

Tags: view, grid

Greeting people,

I found this one: [Oracle SQL Developer - Query results window with grid missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618526/oracle-sql-developer-query-results-window-with-grid-missing), which is close to my question, but not 100%. I understand I have to press F9 to get the Grid view output. My question is how I can ***ALWAYS*** get the grid view without press F9????

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`F5` will not open the grid in SQLDeveloper, you have to use `F9` or `CTRL+Enter`