# ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option - Toad

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

When i execute below SQL in Toad its throws "**ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option**".

```
ALTER TABLE CALCULATE
  ADD (CAL_METHOD VARCHAR2(50), REMARKS VARCHAR2(500));
```

But when execute in SQL Developer its running successful, Is there any issue with SQL / Toad. Please advice me.

Comment: Which version of TOAD and Oracle are you using? When I execute the same syntax, I am able to alter the table.

Comment: Resolved by using F5 instead of Execute statement button in toad.

Comment: Sometimes in PLSQL this problem is displayed because of the length limit of the field names or Constraints, which are more than 30 characters long.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In TOAD I suppose, you need to execute it as a script (press <kbd>F5</kbd>) rather that running it as a statement.

Answer (score 3):

Your SQL is correct but the problem is TOAD restrict Statements and Scripts for each button. I assume the cause of the error is you are trying to run `ALTER TABLE` command using `Execute Statement` or `F9` key. First of all, let's see what is different between **Statement** and **Script**

> <kbd>Execute Statement</kbd> will give you a list of all the results in a
>   sortable table. It will also only run the statement under the cursor
>   (or highlighted). You will be prompted for bind variables when you run
>   the statement (any placeholder: in front of it).
>
> E.g.
>
> ```
> select * from customers where customer_id = :id
> ```
>
> will prompt for a value for id
>
> <kbd>Execute Script</kbd> will execute all statements in the worksheet,
>   and give a text readout of the results. It will not prompt you for the
>   values of bind variables.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/479443/2940265

As you can understand ALTER TABLE returns only a text output. So you have to use `Execute as Script` or `F5`

[image: Execute As Script Toad]

Answer (score 2):

### try this:

```
ALTER TABLE CALCULATE
  ADD (CAL_METHOD VARCHAR2(50));

ALTER TABLE CALCULATE
  ADD (
 REMARKS VARCHAR2(500));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using TOAD 11.0.6 and Oracle database version is 11gR2

See the below scripts which I am able to execute by F5 or by clicking the green arrow as shown in the enclosed screenshot

```
CREATE TABLE calculate (col NUMBER);

ALTER TABLE calculate
  ADD (cal_method VARCHAR2(50), remarks VARCHAR2(500));

SELECT * FROM calculate;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I end up drop the column first then add back

```
ALTER TABLE  SITE_NUMBER DROP COLUMN CREATOR_ID;  
ALTER TABLE  SITE_NUMBER ADD (CREATOR_ID varchar2(12))
```