# Why do I keep getting this error message ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option

Tags: oracle

I am trying to use this syntax to alter the table to define the primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE student ADD CONSTRAINT studentid_pk PRIMARY KEY (studentid);
```

but I keep getting this error message:

> ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option

**What syntax would you recommend?**

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your syntax, that should work fine. You're missing some relevant details for your question. Can you reproduce the problem on livesql.oracle.com?

Comment: The syntax is correct, see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b08c92c6edef2574a8aa50e52354d04f it might be related to the tool you are using.

Comment: Do you already have primary key on the table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option - Toad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44513410/ora-01735-invalid-alter-table-option-toad)